# Nginx install in Mac vs nginx using docker

Tags: macos, docker, nginx, containers, local

Install Nginx on Mac local with brew install nginx. I don’t know why nginx local does not have the conf.d folder and the contents in it. (If you use docker run, there will be /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
But in Mac local I don’t know why there is no

The main configuration in nginx docker access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main in nginx.conf; is open, open access.log but there is nothing there, while local nginx has something as soon as it is opened (and The access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log in local nginx.conf is actually a comment by default)

Later, I found that there is a line in default.conf in nginx docker #access_log /var/log/nginx/host.access.log main; Is this to be turned on?

And in nginx docker, nginx.conf has access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main; but there is still no log. When will this line be used?

Answer (score 0):

i think the location for the nginx configuration file on mac is different.
try to check in
/usr/local/etc/nginx/

Comment: I tried it.  so i wonder why there is no conf.d/ default.conf at the mac local

Comment: For now, I can't be sure why it happened, but I think it happened because it is not official and different versions. CMIIW